# Duplicate class found while importing hyperpay sdk 4.6.0 version

Tags: android, payment-gateway

```
Duplicate class nts.ㇸ found in modules jetified-ipworks3ds_sdk-runtime (ipworks3ds_sdk.aar) and jetified-oppwa.mobile-runtime (oppwa.mobile.aar)
 Duplicate class nts.ㇹ found in modules jetified-ipworks3ds_sdk-runtime (ipworks3ds_sdk.aar) and jetified-oppwa.mobile-runtime (oppwa.mobile.aar)
 Duplicate class nts.ㇽ found in modules jetified-ipworks3ds_sdk-runtime (ipworks3ds_sdk.aar) and jetified-oppwa.mobile-runtime (oppwa.mobile.aar)
 Duplicate class nts.ㇾ found in modules jetified-ipworks3ds_sdk-runtime (ipworks3ds_sdk.aar) and jetified-oppwa.mobile-runtime (oppwa.mobile.aar)
```

When i add the hyperpay sdk 4.6.0 aar file and rebuild error occurs

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Also added but not fixed

Answer (score 1):

Via theirs [official doc](https://hyperpay.docs.oppwa.com/tutorials/mobile-sdk/first-integration)

> Drag and drop `oppwa.mobile.aar` & `ipworks3ds_sdk.aar` (use
> `ipworks3ds_sdk_deploy.aar` for production) **to the "libs" folder** of the
> module where you plan to integrate Mobile SDK

You should only add one of the `ipworks3ds_sdk` to libs folder, depend on your on `Test` or `Live` mode.
If you want to keep both in libs, you can try this(app/build.gradle):

```
// implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.aar"]) //<= remove this

implementation files('libs/oppwa.mobile-4.6.0-release.aar')
implementation files('libs/ipworks3ds_sdk_deploy.aar') //<= comment this if you are on Test mode
//implementation files('libs/ipworks3ds_sdk.aar') //<= un-comment this if you are on Test mode
```